# SendMessage is causing script to hang

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having an issue where the SendMessage() function is causing a script to hang and thus never exiting though it is running the SendMessage like it should (Its task completes). Is there anyway to get around this because I am having a heck of a time killing it from the master script.

```
Stop-job -name offmon
```

or

```
Remove-job -name offmon -force
```

will not kill it. With out the force on remove-job it reports it cannot kill it because it is not finished.

I need to call this many times per day and each time I do it spawns a new powershell.exe eating about 30M of memory.

Note: The code will turn of your monitors if you run it and the "@ needs to be at the beginning of the line (can't tab it over to look nice).

```
start-job -Name offmon -ScriptBlock { 
$HWND = -1
$WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112
$SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170
$MONITOR_ON = -1
$MONITOR_OFF = 2
#Store the C# signature of the SendMessage function. 
$signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
"@
#Add the SendMessage function as a static method of a class
$SendMessage = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name "Win32SendMessage" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
#Invoke the SendMessage Function
$SendMessage::SendMessage($HWND, $WM_SYSCOMMAND, $SC_MONITORPOWER, $MONITOR_OFF)
exit}
```

Also this hangs just the same without start-job so I do not believe it is related to [start-job causes scripts to hang.](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/499499/adding-a-snapin-add-pssnapin-from-within-a-job-start-job-causes-job-to-hang-indefinitely) [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009703). Further this is Win7Ent/2008R2.

Thanks!

Edit: Typos

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but the signature for SendMessage should be SendMessage(IntPtr, uint, IntPtr, IntPtr).

Comment: I don't think so because the actual command goes through, the monitors turn off, without any errors but I could be mistaken.

Comment: are you on a 64bit o.s? if so read all here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891585/sendmessage-is-causing-script-to-hang

Answer (score 4):

Change `SendMessage` to `PostMessage`. It worked for me.

The difference is that `PostMessage` is **asynchronous** and it doesn't have to wait for any response.

Answer (score 1):

Please add

```
Add-Type -Assembly UIAutomationClient
```

and use

```
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(int hWnd, UInt32 hMsg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
```

or

```
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, UInt32 hMsg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
```

And the script will no longer crash

Answer (score 1):

Short version of this script as a batch file command (put this line in a .bat file):

@powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::PostMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)

Comment: Same thing, but from Powershell: https://superuser.com/a/1542141/155147